# Keyboard shortcut to launch dmenu

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome, shortcut-keys, menu

I've got a `snippets` file in my home directory with two simple commands

```
ls
whoami
```

Running the following terminal command utilizes [dmenu](https://tools.suckless.org/dmenu/) to allow me to select a line in my `snippets` file and pipe the output to whatever application I have in focus (usually my terminal):

```
xdotool type $(grep -v '^#' ~/snippets | dmenu -i -l 50 | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

I want to bind `Super+Ins` to run that command above, and have attempted via `Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts > +` and entering the following for the command to issue:

```
gnome-terminal -e "xdotool type $(grep -v '^#' ~/snippets | dmenu -i -l 50 | cut -d' ' -f1)"
```

When I go ahead and use this new keyboard shortcut `Super+Ins` I get the following output

```
(grep-v^#~/snippets|dmenu-i-l50|cut-d -f1)
```

instead of the expected dmenu selection. What am I doing wrong? My OS is Ubuntu 22.04 under GNOME running X11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command substitution will not work from the shortcut definition. It must be run in bash for it to work. Instead, move your `xdotool` command in a small script and have the shortcut definition point to that script instead.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, added `sleep 0.3` to the command, and used the command directly as a shortcut key, but the output from `Super+Ins` is still `grep-v^#~/snippets|dmenu-i-l50|cut-d -f1)` instead of the expected dmenu snippet list. Were you able to get my concept working, or was this just your initial thoughts on how to fix the issue?

Comment: I see. It is the command substitution that does not work from within a shortcut key - command substitution works in scripts and on the bash shell. Thus, xdotool just literally types the string you provided. Changed the answer.